# Convert a pointer that points to a known member of an unknown instance (but known class) to the owning instance

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

Given a pointer that points to a known member of an object, how can I get a pointer to the enclosing object?

Is there a better way than the following? Is it even valid?

```cpp
struct data {
    int a,b;
};

data dummy;
static const std::ptrdiff_t offs_a = reinterpret_cast<char*>(dummy.a) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(dummy);
void main(){
    data d;
    int *v = &(d.a);
    data *owner = reinterpret_cast<data *>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(v) - offs_a);
    owner->b = 1;
}
```

In particular, I don't like the use of the dummy object `dummy` just to determine a pointer offset.
Is there a way to directly cast maybe with the use of a pointer-to-member to specify which (known) member `v` points at?

Comment: You'll get your answer soon, I'm sure, but I just wanted to point out that pointer arithmetic on `void*` is undefined by the C++ standard. You need to be using `char*` , `unsigned char*`, or `std::byte*`.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out! - corrected

Comment: In general, you can't. For some restricted types (essentially, things that would compile as C) you can do this.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Why is that? I would have assumed that every concrete type has a fixed memory layout? The only case where I could imagine indeterminate layout off the top of my head would be involving virtual inheritance (if at all)... Is there any other?

Comment: @burnpanck -- be careful about making assumptions about how things are implemented. Things that look like the most reasonable, most likely, most common approaches are not necessarily required by the standard.

Comment: @burnpanck The standard poses no requirement on what padding can be in an object.  That means that for any other member than the first one (and only for standard layout type), you have no idea what the offset is of the member to the start of the class.  Normally compilers will arrange an object the same way, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: @burnpanck -- that pointer arithmetic is not required to work. Pointer arithmetic only applies to objects in the same array. That's why C has the `offsetof` macro -- let the implementor figure out how to calculate that.

Comment: Absolutely (to all three previous comments). I was hoping that the standard guarantees in some cases a fixed offset and a way to determine that offset (or even better both condensed into one, so that we not even have to know about pointer arithmetic at all!). @andrey showed in his answer, that the condition is _standard layout_ and the way is `offsetof`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `offsetof` macro.

Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof):

> The macro `offsetof` expands to an integral constant expression of type `std::size_t`, the value of which is the offset, in bytes, from the beginning of an object of specified type to its specified member, including padding if any.

It is only guaranteed to work for [standard layout types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout), but for your case it should be fine.

EDIT: The original code could then be written like this:

```
data d;
int *v = &(d.a);
data *owner = reinterpret_cast<data *>(reinterpret_cast<char *>(v) - offsetof(data, a));
owner->b = 1;
```

Comment: Note `offsetof` only gives you the offset from the start of the object to the memory. It doesn't give you the pointer to that object.

Comment: (Note: Since C++17, implementations are allowed to support more types but this is of course not portable: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2709)